# IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/cali/Dropbox/'

Tags: python

I have a function where I am trying to copy an XML document to my Dropbox folder, but I am getting:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/cali/PycharmProjects/Vocabulary/Vocabulary.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1553, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/Vocabulary/Vocabulary.py", line 232, in add_item
    self.sync()
  File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/Vocabulary/Vocabulary.py", line 287, in sync
    copyfile(vocabulary_path, destination_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/cali/Dropbox/'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is the function:

```
def sync(self):

    path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
    vocabulary_path = os.path.join(path, 'Vocabulary', 'Words.xml')
    destination_path = os.path.expanduser('~/Dropbox/')

    copyfile(vocabulary_path, destination_path)
```

How can I overcome the issue?

Comment: You should path a file as a `destination_path`, not just folder. So, just append it with a filename.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps by copying the file to another file, rather than a directory.

```
...
destination_path = os.path.expanduser('~/Dropbox/Words.xml')
...
```